# Comments are in database, don't show up in WordPress backend or frontend

Tags: posts, database, comments

I am in the process of rescuing the content from a WordPress site with a bloated/damaged database. Everything has gone according to plan except for the comments. I can see that the 4000+ comments are indeed in the database's `wp_comments` table, and I verified that the IDs of the associated posts are correct, but none of them show up in the WordPress admin area or the front-end. I haven't been able to find where the issue lies.

Maybe someone in the community has an idea for a possible fix? Thanks.

Edit: to clarify, I already moved the content to a new database, the issue happens on the new WordPress installation. The comments were imported to the database when importing the posts through the export/import tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after going over the database structure, I realized that for some reason all comments status on the table comment_approved had been set to post-trashed. Changing the value of that column to '1' made it all reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have turned on the comments and discussion from the screen options of the posts => http://prntscr.com/m8qac1

And also mark the check mark on the allow comments checkbox showing on the middle/end of the post pages => http://prntscr.com/m8qapd